# Timer - How to display text at certain intervals using a timer?

Tags: android

I have JSON data (about 20 strings I want to display in TextViews) with timestamps in a 30 second period. How would I display the text relative to a 30 second timer?

The json output is a start time, and an end time.
For example:

```
start_time  :   2.7
end_time    :   3.28
content :   just call me      //The text I want to display on screen
```

```
start_time  :   3.76
end_time    :   3.96
content : maybe
```

Comment: make your question clear, please.
your JSON is loading crazy? can you attach a sample of your JSON?
"relative to a 30 second timer" is very vague.

Comment: Yeah I placed a sample above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use interval operator of RxJava. At each 30 second, onNext() method of the observer is invoked.

```
Observable.interval(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            // Run on a background thread
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            // Be notified on the main thread
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribe(new Observer<Long>() {
                @Override
                public void onSubscribe(Disposable d) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onNext(Long value) {
                    // at each 30 second, here is called.
                    System.out.println("onNext: " + value);
                }

                @Override
                public void onError(Throwable e) {
                    System.out.println("onError: " + e.getMessage());
                }

                @Override
                public void onComplete() {

                }
            }
```

Comment: I converted my json to an Arraylist, but I'm confused on how I would integrate the list with this RxJava operation? Edited my sample input above. I also feel this is cleaner than doing a timer with a counter.

Comment: You can call textView.setText and use your array list in onNext() method

Answer (score 2):

You can use java.util.Timer for implementing a timer.

```
new Timer().schedule(task, after);
```

use it in for loop like this:

```
for(int i=0; i<=array.length(); i++){
    new Timer().schedule(task, start_time);
}
```

Also, you can set the timer for removing text from TextView in this way:

```
for(int i=0; i<=array.length(); i++){
        new Timer().schedule(task, start_time);
        new Timer().schedule(taskDelete, end_time);
    }
```

you can define task like this:

```
task = new TimerTask() {
            public void run() {

                handler.post(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        //set text in TextView
                        yourTV.setText("your text);
                    }
                });
            }
        };
```

And, taskDelete like this:

```
taskDelete = new TimerTask() {
            public void run() {

                handler.post(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        //remove text from TextView
                        yourTV.setText("...");
                    }
                });
            }
        };
```

If you want to change the text in textView with animation you can use [TextSwitcher](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextSwitcher.html#setText(java.lang.CharSequence))

Answer (score 0):

you can use a repeating timer. first I would extract the data from the JSON in to List of Strings  and timestamps containing the text and the timestamp ideally modified so that they appear as the long distance in time between each message

```
public class message{
String text;
long timestamp;
 }

    int stringCounter=1
    List<message> textArray; //put the 20 text with timestamp items from the json in here
    // make sure you enter the differences between the timestamps in long 
    //format i.e. instead of "text1" at 1.5s and "text2" at 6.0s you write 
    //"text1" in 1500ms and "text2" in 4500ms and enter that into textArray
    public void rescheduleTimer(int counter){
      mTimer=new Timer("testTimer",true);
      MyTimerClass timerTask=new MyTimerClass();
      mTimer.schedule(timerTask, textArray.get(counter).timestamp);
    }

    yourTextView.setText(textArray.get(0).text);

private class MyTimerClass extends TimerTask {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                yourTextView.setText(textArray.get(stringCounter).text);
                stringcounter++;
                if(stringCounter>=19)mTimer.cancel();
                rescheduleTimer(stringCounter);

            }
        });

    }
};
```

Comment: The JSON received is already premarked with timestamps, for example the first String is at 2.3 seconds, the second string is at 3 seconds, third is at 6.2 seconds. They are not all  increments of 1500 ms.

Comment: in that case you need to create a new timer everytime you execute the last one.